# Jquery dynamic table generating a space that breaks an image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I'm generating a table of Amazon covers and titles for our Amazon Associates store, using YQL to pull the book info from a Google Docs spreadsheet. The below 'append' function gives me an image link with an extra space in it (after 'images/I/') that breaks the link. It gives me:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/%2041XXDPPYBQL._SL150_.jpg
```

or

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/ 41XXDPPYBQL._SL150_.jpg
```

instead of the correct:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41XXDPPYBQL._SL150_.jpg
```

How can I get it to generate the correct link? Do I have to escape something?

`.append('<tr><td class="coverwrap"><a href="http://astore.amazon.com/calvininstitu-20/detail/' + item.ASIN + '"><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/' + item.ImageID + '._SL150_.jpg"></a></td>` [...]

Comment: It appears that `item.ImageID` has a leading space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [@Šime's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas) comment, it looks like there is an extra space in `item.ImageID`. An easy way to fix this is to [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim) the string:

```
.append('<tr><td class="coverwrap"><a href="http://astore.amazon.com/calvininstitu-20/detail/' + item.ASIN + '"><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/' + $.trim(item.ImageID) + '._SL150_.jpg"></a></td> ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your ImageID appears to have a leading space. If you can't fix it at source, you can trim it thus:

```
item.ImageID.replace(/^\s+/, "")
```